# Terraform Fails Intermittently to clone Windows VM using template

Tags: terraform, vsphere

Details
Terrafrom version - Terraform v0.13.3
VCenter Vsphere Version - vSphere Client version 6.7.0.40000

Once in 3 attempts Terraform executes successfully but Sometimes Fails i.e, VM gets created successfully but fails post task with below error.

Failure
[ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: POST [https://192.128.1.1/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association?~action=list-attached-tags](https://192.128.1.1/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association?%7Eaction=list-attached-tags): 401 Unauthorized

2020/09/23 18:35:03 [ERROR] eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: POST [https://192.128.1.1/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association?~action=list-attached-tags](https://192.128.1.1/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association?%7Eaction=list-attached-tags): 401 Unauthorized

Troubleshooting Done:
The account has Administrator role in VCenter
Checked the sessions of the user and terminated the account used by Terraform still no luck.

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Are you sure it's intermittent, i.e. that the successful creations are doing the same tag operations and succeeding? This looks suspiciously related: https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-ruby/issues/47

Comment: Yes I am damn sure one out 3 it is success, not sure what could be the problem, I have terminated sessions thinking it could be due to session related and also checked the user role it is part of Administrator.